# Why does't this code resolve Feb 1st as the 32nd day of the year?

Tags: java

```
public void testCalendar() throws ParseException {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

  SimpleDateFormat timestampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Date d1 = timestampFormat.parse("2011-02-01 09:02:44");

  cal.setTime(d1);

  System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
}
```

I'm trying to get feb 1st as the 32nd day of 2011. 
It gets printed as "1" when I would expect day 32 of the year 2011. Is there something wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a capital `MM` for months in your format pattern:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: winner! that worked, thanks Rob :) (can't accept your answer for another 11 minutes it says)

Comment: What, no "Use JodaTime instead" ;)?

Comment: Use JodaTi... oh... too late.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is reasonable if you're only parsing dates and working with timestamps, but yes: use Joda. :)